# How to add new line to Swift comment for `Quick Help`

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding comments to a class that is shown via 'Quick Help'. I want the descriptions on different lines, how can I do that?

```
/// Description of class Foo - line 1
/// line 2
/// line 3
/// line 4
class Foo {
    
}
```

What is shown in Quick Help:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For multiline comments, use the `/**  */` markers instead. Check out the [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html)
 for more details.

Note that for **Summary**, you can only have 1 line. Every additional line is moved to the **Discussion** section.

```
/**
 Description of class Foo - line 1
 
 line 2
 
 line 3
 
 line 4
 */
class Foo {
    
}
```

[image: Each line renders as a new line in the Quick Help section]

Comment: You can also use the `///` comment prefix on every line and insert blank comment lines with only `///` on them to get the same effect. I agree with aheze that the the `/**` form is better for multi-line comments though. (Voted)

Comment: You can also do it with the inline comment (`///`), you just have to let an empty line (which still needs to starts with the triple slash tho). Note that the `///` version seems to be the preferred way in the Swift standard library and other swift package published by Apple (not really relevant but still good to know).

Comment: @DuncanC @rraphael thanks! Whenever I have multiple lines I prefer the `/**` though, less clutter.